# Como obtener datos de un arraylist de objects

Tags: java

el problema que estoy teniendo es que quiero acceder a las propiedades de un objeto que esta dentro de un arraylist.

```
public float obtenerConsumoCombustibleTrayecto(String marca,String modelo, 
         int anio, float cantidadKMCarretera, float cantidadKMCiudad, 
         int tiempoEspera, int CantidadPersonas)throws AutoNoExiste{

        float Consumo=0;
        float ccar=0f;
        float cciu=0f;


        for(int x=0;x<listaAutos.size();x++){
            Auto a=new Auto(marca , modelo,anio);
            a=listaAutos.get(x);
            if(a.getMarca().equals(marca)){
                if(a.getModelo().equals(modelo)){
                    if(a.getAnio()==anio){
                        ccar=a.getConsumoCarretera();
                        cciu=a.getConsumoCiudad();
                    }
                }
            }
            throw new AutoNoExiste("El auto buscado no se encuentra en el sistema");
            return Consumo;
        }
```

Este es mi metodo pero no estoy accediendo correctamente a las propiedades de mis objetos y no entiendo porque.

Comment: dos dudas, de que tipo son modelo y marca, y por que creas una intancia de  'auto a' y despues le asignas lo que tiene listaAutos en la pos X?

Comment: Que debe hacer el programa? Si bien veo que hay varias cosas para mejorar, aún si funcionara correctamente, no estaría haciendo nada más que quedarse con el los consumos del último auto de la lista.

Comment: Hola te explico basicamente es un metodo que recibe por parametros la marca y el modelo (que son del tipo String) , ademas de otras cosas como el año y demas. Lo que tengo que hacer es buscar en mi arraylist cuales Autos cumplen esa condiciones de marca , modelo y año y si lo encuentra tiene que obtener el consumoCarretera y consumoCiudad en caso de no encontrarlo debe lanzar la excepcion AutoNoExiste

Answer (score 0):

Hola tu codigo deberia funcionar, a menos que este mal tu lista o otro sea el error ,prueba reemplazando esto por tu for.

```
 //instancias el objeto auto
  Auto a=new Auto(marca , modelo,anio);
        for(int x=0;x<listaAutos.size();x++){
            //reemplazas el objeto por el iterador
            a=listaAutos.get(x);
            //comparas si un  objeto tiene los parametros que le pasaste
            if(a.getMarca().equals(marca) && a.getModelo().equals(modelo) && a.getAnio()=anio){

               ccar=a.getConsumoCarretera();
               cciu=a.getConsumoCiudad();
                System.out.println("Auto existe  indice "+x);
 }
```

Fijate que tu lista contenga los datos,se puede llenar objetos de esta forma

```
  ArrayList<Auto> a = new ArrayList<>();
         Auto au = new Auto("Nisan","MO-50",2010,5004,1000,10,8);
          Auto a1 = new Auto("Ford","MO-50",2010,3500,6000,10,8);
         a.add(au);
         a.add(a1);
```